# python if-else only goes to else part

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following simple [python](/questions/tagged/python) code, which checks the user input.

```
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter the number :")
    if (num >= 1 and num <= 5):
        break
    else:
        print "Error! Enter again :"
```

When I give as input `0` or numbers greater than `5` it works correctly, but then I try to give an input from `1` to `5` and the program still goes to the `else` part. Could you help me to find my error?

Comment: Probably due to the fact that "num" is actually a string. You should convert it first. I would think that trying to compare a string with a number would be an error, but it's been awhile since I've written Python.

Comment: `num = int(raw_input("Enter a number"))`

Comment: Fun python fact: you can also write `if 1 <= num <= 5:`

Comment: And that is called Chained Comparison Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num` is a string, not a number. You need to convert the return value of `raw_input` into a number first with `int()`:

```
>>> n = raw_input('Type stuff: ')
Type stuff: 123
>>> type(n)
<type 'str'>
>>> n
'123'
>>> int(n)
123
>>> type(int(n))
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Could you explain me the `In[2]-Out[2]`? Because if the user gives a `string` as input, I also want to reject it.

Comment: @Marievi: `raw_input()` *always* returns strings. It's up to you to interpret what they mean.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to `int` -

```
 num = int(raw_input("Enter the number :"))
```

As `raw_input` read line and converts it to `string` .

Comment: Just of of curiosity, why is this not an error? I can't think of a scenario where it makes sense to compare a string to a number.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You can find more details about this here: [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Comment: @Carcigenicate  That generates an error in Python 3 and above versions.